# Getting error in accessing Interface in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12

I am trying my best but getting error of type in accessing the data. Help needed.

I have a json as below

```
[{
  "productType": "Electronics",
  "modelDetails": [
    {
      "modelId": "I Kall K 48",
      "modelPrice": 759,
      "specifications": {
        "memory": "32 MB RAM | 64 MB ROM",
        "display": "4.57 cm (1.8 inch) Display",
      }
    }, 
    {
      "modelId": "I Kall K 48",
      "modelPrice": 759,
      "specifications": {
        "memory": "32 MB RAM | 64 MB ROM",
        "display": "4.57 cm (1.8 inch) Display",
      }
    }
  ]
}]
```

Below is my ts file with defined Interface.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import productsData from './jsonFile3.json';

interface Product {
    productType: String,
    modelDetails: ModelDetails
}

interface ModelDetails {
    modelId: String,
    modelPrice: Number,
    specifications:Specifications
}

interface Specifications {
  memory: String,
  display: String,
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.less']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'ngapplication';
  name = 'Angular';
  products: Product[] = productsData;
}
```

I am getting error as

```
error TS2322: Type '{ productType: string; modelDetails: { modelId: string; modelPrice: number; specifications: { memory: string; display: string; }; }[]; }; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Product[]'.
```

Also, if there is only single data in modelDetails then it is captured but when it becomes an array of object then even after declaring `modelDetails: ModelDetails[]`, still it is not rendered.

Can anyone help me out in this ??

Thanks

Comment: `modelDetails` in the `Product` interface should be an array. `modelDetails: ModelDetails[]`

Comment: With `modelDetails: ModelDetails[]` in `Product`, I cannot replicate your error: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pmsod5?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @ruth : in your approach you hardcoded the data in a const variable in ts itself. But actually the data is being referred from json file externally. Could you please check it out for external json file ?

Comment: @AbhijeetKumar: Here is a working example with imported object from a JSON file: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zp4zej?file=tsconfig.json. For this to work, you'd need to set two properties in the `tsconfig.json` file. See here: https://medium.com/codeptivesolutions/how-to-import-json-file-in-angular-a2e012948479

Comment: None of the solutions provided are working. The 2 properties for tsconfig.json are already there.
What I found is, if modelDetails is having only single item inside it without [ ], then it is working fine, but once [ ] appears it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, With a combination of Hit-n-Trial method and based on the above response of @Chris, I was able to resolve it.
Below is the solution that I applied :

1. In ts file, ModelDetails defined as array interface :

   ```
    interface Product {
        productType: String,
        modelDetails: ModelDetails[];
    }

    interface ModelDetails {
        modelId: String,
        modelPrice: Number
    }
   ```
2. And in HTML file, rendering part is as below :

   ```
    <div *ngFor="let modelDetail of product.modelDetails">
        <div class="modelId">{{modelDetail.modelId}}</div>
        <div class="modelPrice">{{modelDetail.modelPrice}}</div>
    </div>
   ```

Thanks Everyone for your replies and help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define like;

```
interface Product {
    productType: String,
    modelDetails: ModelDetails[]
}
```

Because in JSON your ModelDetails is an array.

Comment: I have already tried this. In this case the error says property does not exists...  I am missing something minor but unable to figure it out.

Comment: @AbhijeetKumar please show the new error message.

Comment: @ChrisHamilton : here it is 
**Error: src/app/app.component.html:18:34 - error TS2339: Property 'modelId' does not exist on type 'ModelDetails[]'.
18 <div>{{product.modelDetails.modelId}}</div>
src/app/app.component.ts:47:16
47 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.**
....
Likewise, for every item it is giving the same error.

Comment: @AbhijeetKumar As the error message says, you are trying to access a property of the array, you've forgotten to index into the array. Something like `product.modelDetails[0].modelId`, or use an `ngFor` to loop through. If you add your html to the question we can probably help.

Answer (score 0):

Here 'productsData' you are accessing is the object and you are directly trying to assign it to array based variable 'products'. thats why it shows you error. I think you should push 'productsData' as element of array like array.push(productsData). at least try it.

Comment: above solution also applied for  **modelDetails: ModelDetails[] in Product**

Comment: I didn't get it. Can you please provide details on how to make this happen ?